# Selection of multiple similar HTML elements to store its content in an array Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, queryselector

I want to select h3 element content to be stored in an array. So how to select all h3 elements and store its content.
I used querySelectorAll() to select all similar elements but unsuccessful in reaching my target. Thank You!!

```html
<body>
  <ul class="student-list">
    <li class="student-item cf">
      <div class="student-details">
        <h3 class="students">Ethel Dean</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="student-item cf">
      <div class="student-details">
        <h3 class="students">Lawrence Martin</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"I used querySelectorAll() to select all similar elements but unsuccessful in reaching my target."* Show us that code, so we can help you with it.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".students").forEach(el => arr.push(el.innerHTML));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iterable spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in an array literal to get an array from the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on that to get a new array with the text content ([`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) of each of those elements:

```
const contents =
    [...document.querySelectorAll("h3")]
    .map(el => el.textContent);
```

```js
const contents =
    [...document.querySelectorAll("h3")]
    .map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(contents);
```

```html
<ul class="student-list">
     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Ethel Dean</h3>  
        </div>
     </li>

     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Lawrence Martin</h3>
        </div>
     </li>    
</ul>
```

You can also apply `Array.prototype.map` directly to the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` and doing that isn't unusual, but to a beginner it may look fairly odd:

```
const contents = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("h3"),
    el => el.textContent
);
```

```js
const contents = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("h3"),
    el => el.textContent
);
console.log(contents);
```

```html
<ul class="student-list">
     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Ethel Dean</h3>  
        </div>
     </li>

     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Lawrence Martin</h3>
        </div>
     </li>    
</ul>
```

Since you're just searching on the tag name, you could also use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) which in some cases may be much faster (though it's unlikely to matter). Both of the above work on the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that `getElementsByTagName` returns:

```js
const contents1 =
    [...document.getElementsByTagName("h3")]
    .map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(contents1);
const contents2 = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName("h3"),
    el => el.textContent
);
console.log(contents2);
```

```html
<ul class="student-list">
     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Ethel Dean</h3>  
        </div>
     </li>

     <li class="student-item cf">
        <div class="student-details">
           <h3 class="students">Lawrence Martin</h3>
        </div>
     </li>    
</ul>
```